# Entering matrices interactively

Tags: matrix, scripting, user-interface

I am looking for a way to enter an `m*n` matrix interactively using a dialog or a Graphical User Interface(GUI). Further, I would like to use this matrix later for computations.

So far, I have the following code:

```
lin = Input["Quantas Linhas ?: "];

col = Input["Quantas Colunas? : "];

a = {}; b = {}; nl = {};

m1 = 1;

While[m1 <= lin col, 
 AppendTo[a, Input["Elementos da Primeira Matriz:  "]]; m1++];

m2 = 1;

While[m2 <= lin col, 
 AppendTo[b, Input["Elementos da Primeira Matriz:  "]]; m2++];

matriz1 = Partition[a, col];
matriz2 = Partition[b, col];

MatrixForm[matriz1]



MatrixForm[matriz2]

i = 1;
k = 1;
While[k <= col, 
 While[i <= col, 
  AppendTo[nl, matriz1[[k]][[i]] + matriz2[[k]][[i]]] ; i++]; k++];
nl
```

Comment: It would have been more useful if you had added some verbal comments explaining the task at hand rather than a long title and a chunk of code

Comment: Have you see in the Toolbar under item "Insert" and "Table/Matrix" and then "New" . There you can input a matrix graphically.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach to present the user with an entire matrix of placeholders at once, which should make it easier to quickly enter a matrix without getting confused about which entry is being edited:

[image]

```
{m, n} = {2, 3};
DialogInput[{
  "Enter matrix:",
  Style[
   Framed[
    MatrixForm@Table[
      Style[
       RawBoxes@TagBox["\[Placeholder]", # &, BoxID -> "Placeholder"],
        Deployed -> False
       ],
      m, n
      ],
    Background -> White,
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
    ImageSize -> Full,
    FrameStyle -> LightGray
    ],
   Editable -> True
   ],
  ChoiceButtons[{
    DialogReturn[
     ToExpression@
      FirstCase[NotebookRead@Cells[][[2]], 
       FrameBox[g_, ___] :> g, $Failed, All]]
    }]},
 WindowSize -> {400, FitAll},
 ShowCursorTracker -> False,
 WindowTitle -> None,
 Selectable -> True, 
 Initialization :> Function[MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
    FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind[
     FE`BoxReference[
      #,
      {{"Placeholder"}},
      FE`BoxOffset -> {FE`BoxChild[1]},
      FE`SearchStart -> "StartFromBeginning"
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
 ]
```

Notes:

- The `Selectable->True` on the notebook and `Deployed->False` on the individual placeholders ensures that only the placeholders can be selected and edited.
- The `TagBox[...,BoxID->...]` and `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind `` trick is needed to select the first placeholder upon showing the notebook (this is based on what `DialogInput` does internally) - a normal `NotebookFind` did not work for me.
- The `ToExpression[...]` part in the `ChoiceButtons` part selects the correct part of the notebook, and converts the entire matrix as an expression, making it usable for the rest of the code.
- Most of the rest is styling, which can be adapted as desired. I based the options on those from `DialogInput` and tried to mimic the style of an `InputField` for the matrix input.

Answer (score 2):

I do not use `Input` myself, but may be this could work for you

```
nRows = Input["Number of Rows? "];
nCols = Input["Numbers of Cols? : "];
mat = Table[0, {n, nRows}, {m, nCols}];

Do[
 Do[
  e = Input["Element (" <> ToString@n <> "," <> ToString[m] <> ")?"];
  mat[[n, m]] = e
  ,
  {n, 1, nRows}
  ]
 ,
 {m, 1, nCols}
 ]
```

[image]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Input` originates from Mathematica v1.0. Modal windows are, in general, especially for series of single inputs considered bad UI design. I'd consider `TableView`, `Grid` of `InputField`s, or such. This approach typically involves `Dynamic`, which is its own subject, though.

Comment: @kirma I think you meant this as comment to OP not me. I am simply using what they have.

Comment: Yes, sort of, trying not to be too intimidating to a new contributor though.